# Is it safe to manually make System redirect to RP in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, url-rewrite

[image: Screenshot]

Is it safe in Magento to update the *target path* and `Options` using some sql query?

Suppose in the attached screenshot if I update the highlighted target path to *contacts.html* and options to *RP* ( 301 Redirect ) what can be the adverse effects?

Is it a safe practice?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is not safe. You ignore all validations which are implemented in the PHP layer.

Comment: If  I delete a System url and create a custom and again re-index than the System one is again generated.How to overcome this?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. If you generate a rewrite and mark it as not system, then it is not deleted before reindex